# Blackbox exporter refuses to verify endpoints which use selfSigned certificates, openshift cluster

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, openshift

We have an openshift cluster with a prometheus operator monitoring stack. Blacbkox exporter is deployed, configured and is running. I want to probe `/actuator/health` endpoints of Spring Boot applications. These endpoints are https endpoints using selfSigned certificates.

I configured a serviceMonitor and a Probe custom resource in 2 different namespaces, these namespaces contain the same application. Every probe attempt fails right now.

The logs by the serviceMonitor say the following:

`level=info msg="Invalid HTTP response status code, wanted 2xx" status_code=400`

I believe this happens because the endpoint is a https endpoint, but if I specify scheme: https in the config it just plain stops the probing.

The logs by the Probe say the following:

`level=error msg="Error for HTTP request" err="Get \"https://appIP:port/actuator/health\": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"`

I tried giving the probe a service ca to work with, did not work. I gave it the cert and key used by the app and it did not work, says the same.

Any idea what I should do? Configs below.

You'll notice Probe config does not have a ca object right now, but it gave the same log.

(note: `tlsConfig: insecureSkipVerify: true` does not skip the verification process, which is weird)

Blackbox exporter yaml:

```
data:
  blackbox.yaml: |
    modules:
      http_2xx:
        http:
          no_follow_redirects: true
          method: GET
          preferred_ip_protocol: ip4
          valid_http_versions:
          - HTTP/1.1
          - HTTP/2
          valid_status_codes: []
          tls_config:
            insecure_skip_verify: true
        prober: http
        timeout: 10s
```

serviceMonitor yaml:

```
spec:
  endpoints:
    - interval: 30s
      params:
        module:
          - http_2xx
      path: /probe
      relabelings:
        - action: replace
          sourceLabels:
            - __address__
          targetLabel: __param_target
        - action: replace
          replacement: 'exporter:port'
          targetLabel: __address__
        - action: replace
          sourceLabels:
            - __param_target
          targetLabel: instance
        - action: labelmap
          regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
      scrapeTimeout: 10s
  jobLabel: jobLabel
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: component
```

Probe yaml:

```
spec:
  interval: 30s
  module: http_2xx
  prober:
    path: /probe
    url: 'exporter.namespace.svc:port'
  targets:
    staticConfig:
      static:
        - 'https://app.namespace.svc:port/actuator/health'
  tlsConfig:
    cert:
      secret:
        key: key
        name: secret-name
    keySecret:
      key: key
      name: secret-name
```

Thank you for the help in advance!